# Flagging comments

Tags: feature-request

While flagging questions, there is a detailed system explaining exactly what each option means, but there is no such thing while flagging comments. The help section also does not give any specific examples. Can a system for flagging comments be created just like the one for flagging questions?

Answer (score 1):

Because comments are designed to be ephemeral and second-class objects, we don't maintain nearly as much formality in dealing with them. Take you best guess and go with it.

It bears repeating: any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason or none. Nothing important should be left in the comments: important ideas should make their way into first class posts lest they be lost.

Comment: I just wanted to know what option should I use for "Thanks" comments.

Comment: Hmmm...there used to be "noise or pointless", didn't there? Any way, I'd probably use "too chatty".

Comment: @user80551 why would you want to flag thank you comments, what would be the point of this? Saying thank you and being grateful for help obtained helps establish and maintain a good helpful collegial atmosphere on Physics SE. As discussed [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4279/2751) there is in principle nothing wrong with being thankful, so it does not need to be flagged.

Comment: No, what @Dilaton says is not true. Once a thank-you comment has been seen by the OP, it has served its purpose and there's no reason it needs to stay, so it should be flagged at that point and deleted. (If you flag a thank-you comment that has _just_ been posted, we mods may - at our discretion - wait a little while before deleting it, so that the OP sees it.) The permanent way to express thanks is by upvoting.

Comment: @DavidZ I really thought that we have settled that [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4279/2751) and I am sorry to hear that you disagree with having a nice, friendly, collegial and helpful atmosphere here where everybody feels welcome as people agreed upon in the other post that thankful comments are useful for this ... :-/

Comment: @Dilaton it was settled, but not with the conclusion you're stating here. (Also, you don't seem to understand what exactly it is I'm saying. See my last comment.)